# Bash - send all output to a log file, BUT show errors

Tags: bash, shell, unix, file-descriptor, io-redirection

Is it possible within a bash script, to make all output, except the output i specifically output with echo, go to a log file, BUT if there's errors in the output it should show in the terminal (and the log file also ofcourse)?

Comment: Can you confirm that you want these 3 kinds of output? 1) your echos should only appear on the console, 2) other standard output should only appear in the log file and 3) error output should appear in both the console and the log file

Comment: Yes exactly Aaron

Comment: So you want only output from `echo` to appear on stdout? What about `printf`?

Comment: Im only using 'echo' in my script to show status to the user.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do by using an additional file descriptor:

```
#!/bin/bash

# open fd=3 redirecting to 1 (stdout)
exec 3>&1

# redirect stdout/stderr to a file but show stderr on terminal
exec >file.log 2> >(tee >(cat >&3))

# function echo to show echo output on terminal
echo() {
   # call actual echo command and redirect output to fd=3
   command echo "$@" >&3
}

# script starts here
echo "show me"
printf "=====================\n"
printf "%s\n" "hide me"
ls foo-foo
date
tty
echo "end of run"

# close fd=3
exec 3>&-
```

After you run your script it will display following on terminal:

```
show me
ls: cannot access 'foo-foo': No such file or directory
end of run
```

If you do `cat file.log` then it shows:

```
=====================
hide me
ls: cannot access 'foo-foo': No such file or directory
Fri Dec  2 14:20:47 EST 2016
/dev/ttys002
```

- On terminal we're only getting output of `echo` command and all the errors.
- In the log file we're getting error and remaining output from script.

Answer (score 3):

UNIX terminals usually provide two output *file decriptors*, `stdout` and `stderr`, both of which go to the terminal by default.

Well behaved programs send their "standard" output to `stdout`, and errors to `stderr`. So for example `echo` writes to stdout. `grep` writes matching lines to `stdout`, but if something goes wrong, for example a file can't be read, the error goes to `stderr`.

You can redirect these with `>` (for `stdout`) and `2>` (for `stderr`). So:

```
 myscript >log 2>errors
```

Writes output to `log` and errors to `errors`.

So part of your requirement can be met simply with:

```
 command >log
```

... errors will continue to go to the terminal, via stdout.

Your extra requirement is "except the output i specifically output with echo".

It might be enough for you that your `echo`s go to stderr:

```
 echo "Processing next part" >&2
```

The `>&2` redirects `stdout` from this command to `stderr`. This is the standard way of outputting errors (and sometimes informational output) in shell scripts.

If you need more than this, you might want to do something more complicated with more file descriptors. Try: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor

Well behaved UNIX programs tend to avoid doing complicated things with extra file descriptors. The convention is to restrict yourself to `stdout` and `stderr`, with any further outputs being specified as filenames in the command line parameters.

Comment: One minor nit-pick... it's not the UNIX terminal that provides stdin, stdout, and stderr. Even processes that are not running in a terminal have those three file descriptors at startup (important distinction because many daemons just close all three first thing). It's really just a feature of the UNIX process model... I suppose you could even call it part of the API...